# java.net.URI encoding exception in Zuul gateway exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, netflix-zuul

There is a Zuul application that is being run by Spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.

When I request as `http://192.168.10.84:8080/app/rest/micro1/inquiry/printCarInquiryList/1?param={%22storeHouseId%22:%22%22,%22storeHouseName%22:%22%22,%22storeHouseType%22:%22%22,%22plaqueSeries%22:%22%22,%22productionYearFrom%22:%22-1%22,%22productionYearTo%22:%22-1%22,%22overallInquery%22:false,%22edited%22:false,%22confirmerCount%22:%22-1%22,%22reportStoreHouseType%22:%22-1%22,%22plaqueNumber%22:%22%22,%22motorNumber%22:%22%22,%22motorNumberOperator%22:%227%22,%22chassisNumber%22:%22%22,%22chassisNumberOperator%22:%227%22,%22storeHouseShowType%22:%221%22,%22havePlaque%22:%22-1%22,%22isFilterByStoreHouseStatus%22:true,%22storeHouseList%22:[%221518691%22],%22goodsStatus%22:null,%22statusId%22:%22-1%22,%22goodsDeleted%22:null,%22formType%22:1,%22searchFilter%22:%22%22,%22order%22:%22%20e.samapelItem.id%20%22,%22pageNumber%22:0,%22pageSize%22:%227%22,%22plaqueType%22:%22-1%22}`

the following exception is raised:

> Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at
>   index 95:
>   http://192.168.10.84:8080/app/rest/micro1/inquiry/printCarInquiryList/1?param={%id%22:%22%22,%22storeHouseName%22:%22%22,%22storeHouseType%22:%22%22,%22plaqueSeries%22:%22%22,%22productionYearFrom%22:%22-1%22,%22productionYearTo%22:%22-1%22,%22overallInquery%22:false,%22edited%22:false,%22confirmerCount%22:%22-1%22,%22reportStoreHouseType%22:%22-1%22,%22plaqueNumber%22:%22%22,%22motorNumber%22:%22%22,%22motorNumberOperator%22:%227%22,%22chassisNumber%22:%22%22,%22chassisNumberOperator%22:%227%22,%22storeHouseShowType%22:%221%22,%22havePlaque%22:%22-1%22,%22isFilterByStoreHouseStatus%22:true,%22storeHouseList%22:[%221518691%22],%22goodsStatus%22:null,%22statusId%22:%22-1%22,%22goodsDeleted%22:null,%22formType%22:1,%22searchFilter%22:%22%22,%22order%22:%22%20e.samapelItem.id%20%22,%22pageNumber%22:0,%22pageSize%22:%227%22,%22plaqueType%22:%22-1%22}
>   at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848) ~[na:1.8.0_181] at
>   java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021) ~[na:1.8.0_181] at
>   java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3111) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>   at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053) ~[na:1.8.0_181] at
>   java.net.URI.(URI.java:588) ~[na:1.8.0_181] at
>   java.net.URI.create(URI.java:850) ~[na:1.8.0_181]

whereas there is the following configuration:

```
@Bean
    public ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory webServerFactory() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        factory.addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(Connector connector) {
                connector.setProperty("relaxedQueryChars", "|{}[]");
            }
        });
        return factory;
    }
```

where is wrong?

Comment: Configuring Tomcat with custom `relaxedQueryChars` has no effect on what characters are accepted by `URI.create`. It's `URI.create` that's failing. It looks to me like you haven't encoded your URI correctly.

Comment: How do I fix the problem?

Comment: What's the query string supposed to be in its raw, unencoded form?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I do not undrestand your mean.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I have changed the url to simple url like `http://192.168.10.84:8080/app/rest/micro1/inquiry/printCarInquiryList/1?param={id:1}`, again same exception is raised, the problem is character `{`

Comment: @AndyWilkinson the project is located       https://github.com/matin-reza/OAuth2

Comment: Why this configuration work correctly in spring boot 1x but dose not work in boot 2x?

Comment: @aliakbarazizkhani It is solved by zuul filter. Faghat vote yadet nare. Ham be soal va ham be javab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to solve the problem is to decode the some characters that are sensitive such as `{` and so on, but when there is a application that has near to 1000 JSP files in which these characters are not encoded, this way is either impossible or hard to apply in all points in which these characters are used. Consequently the problem is solved by `ZUUL Filter` like this:

```
@Component
public class CharacterEncodingZuulFilter extends ZuulFilter {


    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 10000;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

        Map<String, String[]> qp = new HashMap<>();
        String s = "";
        try {
            s = ctx.getRequest().getQueryString().replaceAll("\\{", URLEncoder.encode("{", "UTF-8"));
            s = s.replaceAll("}", URLEncoder.encode("}", "UTF-8"));
            s = s.replaceAll("\\[", URLEncoder.encode("[", "UTF-8"));
            s = s.replaceAll("]", URLEncoder.encode("]", "UTF-8"));

            HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();

            CustomRequestWrapper wrapped = new CustomRequestWrapper(request, qp, s);

            ctx.setRequest(wrapped);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the `{` and `}` characters in the query portion of the URI. They should be replaced with `%7B` and `%7D` respectively.

Comment: I know your solution but due to doing your solution, i must change more than 1000 points of jsp files of our microservices

Comment: Is there configuration in Zuul is which the character { is skipped??????